# Site for reading the same news article in English and Chinese (简体中文）

Tags: vocabulary, practice

Previously I used to regularly go to a news site that had articles in English that allowed you to immediately switch to Chinese for the same article.

It also had good information on the Chinese side for English readers to introduce when difficult grammer or idioms were used.

I'm hoping someone knows of this site or something similar.

This site was awesome for building vocabulary.

Comment: You say "was", "used to" and other verbs in the past tense because the site doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: @Alenanno - Because I haven't visited for a while. And after a reasonable search just now, I can't seem to find it.

Comment: If you find it, do you mind sharing the link here? It would be interesting for everyone... :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know two great sites just like you said. Hope you like it.

[东西网](http://dongxi.net) and [译言网](http://www.yeeyan.org/).

Comment: With the first link, how to find the original article in English? I can see how to do it with the second one. Thanks!

Comment: 东西网 is now a broken link.  It seems the second one is for books (not news) and requires purchasing.

Answer (score 2):

[Global Voices](http://zh.globalvoicesonline.org/hans/) is a social site for hosting translations of articles in other languages. [Popup Chinese has a tool](http://popupchinese.com/tools/newsinchinese) to help you translate Chinese articles, but they don't have full translations of the articles.

I haven't used either of these sites, I've just seen them mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: Mum..it seems it's blocked by gfw. :p

Answer (score 2):

I was very surprised to learn today that the [Chinese edition of the New York Times](https://cn.nytimes.com/) has a side-by-side mode suitable for more advanced, fluent readers.

(For those unfamiliar with the characters: In the upper right corner of a Chinese article, you can click on "双语" (shuāng yǔ), which translates to "Bilingual". The other two options are 中 (zhōng) and 英 (yīng), for Chinese and English, respectively.)

[image]

Clicking on 双语 brings you to the following mode:

[image]